# How to play merge youtube audio video stream and play on web page?

Tags: python, html, audio, video, youtube

I want to embed youtube video on my page and track start/stop and finish video event which i can't do with iframe but i extract two urls using youtube_dl one is for audio stream and other one is for video stream. but now i am unable to understand how i can play it on web together. sorry for my poor english.

```
youtube_dl -g <youtube-url>
```

Audio Url

```
https://r2---sn-h0aupoxu-3ipe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1452702118&initcwndbps=581250&keepalive=yes&key=yt6&sver=3&gcr=pk&source=youtube&signature=6563CECA1D5288261C481C060284DB05DC2E3527.CC500E44799AB305AD7B26B7EBC34149C1C3BFD6&upn=_AAJt6p8tCU&clen=42107678&gir=yes&ipbits=0&lmt=1449649957340911&fexp=9407190%2C9416075%2C9416126%2C9416402%2C9418200%2C9420452%2C9422596%2C9422968%2C9423662%2C9425957%2C9426472%2C9426504%2C9426719%2C9426757%2C9427016&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ip=202.142.170.44&mm=31&mn=sn-h0aupoxu-3ipe&id=o-AMeDYdwZd-wUxztM1nmJ3bjW98AF62WYrc8BzhZbIutN&itag=251&dur=2709.201&mime=audio%2Fwebm&requiressl=yes&ms=au&mt=1452680392&mv=m&pl=24&ratebypass=yes
```

Video Url

```
https://r2---sn-h0aupoxu-3ipe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=e959362f7f7270b3&itag=136&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&gcr=pk&mn=sn-h0aupoxu-3ipe&mm=31&ms=au&mv=m&pl=24&ratebypass=yes&mime=video/mp4&gir=yes&clen=352468285&lmt=1440335051714588&dur=2709.200&signature=4CE70CF3A74F84029E9A09332D52496E74709F09.70D5812EF7CB413AF5DE2EBA445F118205E165F8&sver=3&mt=1452680392&fexp=9407190,9416075,9416126,9416402,9418200,9420452,9422596,9422968,9423662,9425957,9426472,9426504,9426719,9426757,9427016&upn=l4TRn6jSYMQ&key=dg_yt0&ip=202.142.170.44&ipbits=0&expire=1452702120&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,gcr,mn,mm,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,mime,gir,clen,lmt,dur
```

video tag is not playing video but this url is working fine with VLC player but vlc play it without audio.

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://r2---sn-h0aupoxu-3ipe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=e959362f7f7270b3&itag=136&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&gcr=pk&mn=sn-h0aupoxu-3ipe&mm=31&ms=au&mv=m&pl=24&ratebypass=yes&mime=video/mp4&gir=yes&clen=352468285&lmt=1440335051714588&dur=2709.200&signature=4CE70CF3A74F84029E9A09332D52496E74709F09.70D5812EF7CB413AF5DE2EBA445F118205E165F8&sver=3&mt=1452680392&fexp=9407190,9416075,9416126,9416402,9418200,9420452,9422596,9422968,9423662,9425957,9426472,9426504,9426719,9426757,9427016&upn=l4TRn6jSYMQ&key=dg_yt0&ip=202.142.170.44&ipbits=0&expire=1452702120&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,gcr,mn,mm,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,mime,gir,clen,lmt,dur
" type="video/mp4">

  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

JSON From i got these urls.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgrBOXyF8UAODRiUkQ2dzd1MTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What have tried thus far? Care to add it to your question?

Comment: @Jim please have a look now